# 'b' character added when using numpy loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.4

I tried to create an array from a text file.
I saw earlier that numpy had a method `loadtxt`, so I try it, but it add some junk character before each row...

```
# my txt file

    .--``--.
.--`        `--.
|              |
|              |
`--.        .--`
    `--..--`

# my python v3.4 program

import numpy as np
f = open('tile', 'r')
a = np.loadtxt(f, dtype=str, delimiter='\n')
print(a)

# my print output

["b'    .--``--.    '"
 "b'.--`        `--.'"
 "b'|              |'"
 "b'|              |'"
 "b'`--.        .--`'"
 "b'    `--..--`    '"]
```

What are these 'b' and double quotes ? And where do they come from ?
I tried some solution picked from internet, like open the file with codecs, change the dtype by 'S20', 'S11', and a lot of other things which don't work...
What I expect is an array of unicode strings which look like this :

```
[['    .--``--.    ']
 ['.--`        `--.']
 ['|              |']
 ['|              |']
 ['`--.        .--`']
 ['    `--..--`    ']]
```

Info:
I'm using python 3.4 and numpy from the debian stable repository

Comment: I already check this question before, and, OK!, b is for byte, but why is it _inside_ a double quote string ? I have to re-use this array later for replace some characters in another array, according to an index. So if I have a b and 2 extra simple quotes, it will break the later program.

Comment: Why are you using `loadtxt` to load a file like that?  `loadtxt` is designed for columns of data separated by commas or some other delimiter.  You could just as easily read that file with pure python; e.g. something like `with open('tile') as f: a = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines() if not line.startswith('#')]`

Comment: Simple : I'm a total beginner in Python. I began to use it for 1 week. I more accurate in web language. So I appears to me a bit confusing :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`np.loadtxt` and `np.genfromtxt` operate in byte mode, which is the default string type in Python 2.  But Python 3 uses unicode, and marks bytestrings with this `b`.

I tried some variations, in an `python3 ipython` session:

```
In [508]: np.loadtxt('stack33655641.txt',dtype=bytes,delimiter='\n')[0]
Out[508]: b'    .--``--.'
In [509]: np.loadtxt('stack33655641.txt',dtype=str,delimiter='\n')[0]
Out[509]: "b'    .--``--.'"
...
In [511]: np.genfromtxt('stack33655641.txt',dtype=str,delimiter='\n')[0]
Out[511]: '.--``--.'
In [512]: np.genfromtxt('stack33655641.txt',dtype=None,delimiter='\n')[0]
Out[512]: b'.--``--.'
In [513]: np.genfromtxt('stack33655641.txt',dtype=bytes,delimiter='\n')[0]
Out[513]: b'.--``--.'
```

`genfromtxt` with `dtype=str` gives the cleanest display - except it strips blanks.  I may have to use a converter to turn that off.  These functions are meant to read `csv` data where (white)spaces are separators, not part of the data.

`loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` are over kill for simple text like this.  A plain file read does nicely:

```
In [527]: with open('stack33655641.txt') as f:a=f.read()
In [528]: print(a)
    .--``--.
.--`        `--.
|              |
|              |
`--.        .--`
    `--..--`

In [530]: a=a.splitlines()
In [531]: a
Out[531]: 
['    .--``--.',
 '.--`        `--.',
 '|              |',
 '|              |',
 '`--.        .--`',
 '    `--..--`']
```

(my text editor is set to strip trailing blanks, hence the ragged lines).

---

`@DSM's` suggestion:

```
In [556]: a=np.loadtxt('stack33655641.txt',dtype=bytes,delimiter='\n').astype(str)
In [557]: a
Out[557]: 
array(['    .--``--.', '.--`        `--.', '|              |',
       '|              |', '`--.        .--`', '    `--..--`'], 
      dtype='<U16')
In [558]: a.tolist()
Out[558]: 
['    .--``--.',
 '.--`        `--.',
 '|              |',
 '|              |',
 '`--.        .--`',
 '    `--..--`']
```

Comment: I think `np.loadtxt("tile", dtype=bytes, delimiter="\n").astype(str)` might work, but I agree completely with the overkill point.

Answer (score 9):

Python3 is working with Unicode. I had the same issue when using `loadtxt` with `dtype='S'`. But using `dtype='U` as `Unicode string` in both `numpy.loadtxt` or `numpy.genfromtxt`, it will give output without `b`

```
a=numpy.loadtxt('filename',dtype={'names':('col1','col2','col3'),'formats':('U10','U10','i4')},delimiter=',')

print(a)
```

Comment: This worked great for me on Python3.  Should be the preferred answer on Python3.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `np.genfromtxt('your-file', dtype='U')`.

Comment: Do not forget to specify a string length`dtype='U10'` as without the 10 you'll just get an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the most 'pythonic' or best solution, but definitely gets the job done using numpy.loadtxt in python3. I am aware that it is a "dirty" solution, but it works for me.

```
import numpy as np
def loadstr(filename):
    dat = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=str)
    for i in range(0,np.size(dat[:,0])):
        for j in range(0,np.size(dat[0,:])):
            mystring = dat[i,j]
            tick = len(mystring) - 1 
            dat[i,j] = mystring[2:tick]

    return (dat)

data = loadstr("somefile.txt")
```

This will import a 2D array from a text file via numpy, strip off the "b'" and "'" from the beginning and end of each string, and return a stripped string array named "data".

Are there better ways? Probably.

Does this work? Yup. I use it enough that I've got this function in my own Python module.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and for me the simplest way turned out to use the csv library. 
**You get your desired output by:**

```
import csv
def loadFromCsv(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as file:
        list=[elem for elem in csv.reader(file,delimiter='\n')]
    return list

a=loadFromCsv('tile')
print(a)
```